# How to pin photo album to start in Windows 10 Mobile

Tags: windows-10-mobile, photos, pin-to-start

Is there any way to pin a photo album to start screen with Windows 10 Mobile.
This feature is available with Windows Phone 8.1.
Has Microsoft removed this feature or they changed the ways to access it?

Answer (score 1):

no, u cant! this setting has been removed from windows 10 mobile! :(